# JQuery cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, clone

I am stuck on this problem. I am coding a task platform app. Whenever I try to save, the task clones itself. After each "Save Changes," there are more and more clones. I have rewritten the code so many times. But still, I am not successful. Please help me to find the error.

```
$("#taskSave").click(() => {
    const task = {
        id: Date.now(),
        imageUrl: $("#imageInput").val(),
        title: $("#titleInput").val(),
        description: $("#descriptionInput").val(),
        type: $("#typeInput").val(),
    }; 

    $("#overlay").hide();
    todos.push(task);
    saveStorage(todos);

    // reset input values
    $("#imageInput").val("");
    $("#titleInput").val("");
    $("#descriptionInput").val("");
    $("#typeInput").val("");
});

function saveStorage(todos) {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    display(todos);
};

function display(todos) {
    $("#taskBoard").innerHTML = "";
    // .html("");

    todos.forEach(item => {
        let c = document.createElement("div");
        c.setAttribute("class", "card");
        c.setAttribute('id', item.id);
        c.innerHTML = `
            <div class="cardTop">
                <div class="binContainer">
                    <div class="binImage"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="${item.imageUrl}" alt="task image">
            <h2>${item.title}<h2>
            <p>${item.description}</p>
            <div class="cardType">${item.type}</div>
        `;

        $("#taskBoard").append(c);
        // end 
    });
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What does the saveStorage function do? post the code of that function, because here I don't see particular problems.

Comment: On SO you can edit your initial question. I edited your question. Now I check with the code you added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a minimal working example, and the problem is in the cleanup of the HTML. You cannot use `innerHTML` on the JQuery object, or you use its `html` function or you need to retrieve the javascript object with `$("#taskBoard")[0]`.

```
    // You can use:

    $("#taskBoard").html("");
    // or 
    // document.getElementById("taskBoard").innerHTML  = "";
    // or 
    // $("#taskBoard")[0].innerHTML = "";

    // But not:
    // $("#taskBoard").innerHTML = "";
```

[The working example here on JSFiddle (on SO dont work localStorage)](https://jsfiddle.net/1wanqg5e/)

```js
let todos = [];
$("#taskSave").click(() => {
    const task = {
        id: Date.now()
    }; 
    todos.push(task);
        saveStorage(todos);
});

function saveStorage(todos) {
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    display(todos);
        console.log(todos);
};

function display(todos) {
    $("#taskBoard").html("");
    // or 
    // document.getElementById("taskBoard").innerHTML  = "";
    // or 
    // $("#taskBoard")[0].innerHTML = "";
    // But not
    // $("#taskBoard").innerHTML = "";
    

    todos.forEach(item => {
        let c = document.createElement("div");
        c.innerHTML = `
            <p>${item.id}</p>
        `;

        $("#taskBoard").append(c);
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="taskSave">
SAVE
</button>

<div id="taskBoard">

</div>
```